# replacement for readlink() function in windows

Tags: c++, linux, readlink

readLink() is present in linux and is defined in unistd.h,is there any similar type function in windows please provide or else if we can make a function with similar functionality.**I want to use the same functionality as readLink() please provide a user defined function for the replacement of the function** in case no predefined function is there
provided snap of the code

```
        char buffer[2048];

        readlink("/proc/self/exe", buffer, 2048);

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << buffer;
        std::string exeFile = ss.str();
        std::string directory;

        const size_t last_slash_idx = exeFile.rfind('/');
        if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
        {
            directory = exeFile.substr(0, last_slash_idx);
        }
        return directory;
    #endif
```

Comment: `readlink` is specific to Linux. Are you using visual studio to build a linux application? If not, what do you expect `readlink` to do on Windows which doesn't have symlinks?

Comment: yes i am using visual studio the application is should be working for linux and windows as well

Comment: That's not how things work. A binary built for Windows will not run in Linux (without other magic).

Comment: my application can detect the platform of machine and can work as accordingly without user input

Comment: readlink is not applicable to Windows. You have to work out what you want the program to do in that case.

Comment: that is my point to post the question if there is any similar function in windows

Comment: can form a function which can work as readLink()?

Comment: You are missing the point. Readlink and its function is not relevant for Windows. You need to work out what the linux version is doing with readlink and not just looking at readlink on its own.

Comment: ok thanks for support

Comment: @kaylum, nodejs supports this function on windows, so that's possible.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't have a [**readlink**(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) equivalent, but it *does* have a [**realpath**(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath) equivalent: [`GetFinalPathNameByHandleW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew).

See also: ["How do I get information about the target of a symbolic link?" by Ramond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100212-00/?p=14963).

Pseudo-code is as follows, error checking omitted:

```c
HANDLE hPath = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
DWORD len = GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(hPath, NULL, 0, FILE_NAME_OPENED);
WCHAR* realPathBuf = new WCHAR[len+1];
GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(hPath, realPathBuf, len, FILE_NAME_OPENED);
```

Note that `realPathBuf` may be a "local UNC" path, starting with `\\?\`.

Comment: You don't need `GENERIC_READ`, change it to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as stated in the comments Windows does not have a readlink() link api as such. That said the code given in the sample is doing something that really doesn't needed to handled directly by the program. Linux system api handles links for you. Also readlink does not null terminate it just returns raw data. That said QFile offers a platform independent api to resolve links. `QFile::symLinkTarget` provides a way to get the link target on both windows and unix without your program needing to mess with the OS specific side of this.

The windows process for doing this is not a one liner as it is on linux/unix systems. In fact there are actually two different types of links on windows. I highly recommend going through a framework such as Qt when trying to do cross platform I/O. Windows is a very different animal that your typical linux/unix system. For one thing it is not of POSIX system must linux/unix systems are.

Answer (score 0):

This code on Windows works as readlink on Linux. Just add error and insufficient size buffer handling:

```
int readlink(const char* pathname, char* link, size_t linksize)
{
    HANDLE h = CreateFileA(pathname, 0, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
    char buffer[MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
    DeviceIoControl(h, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwBytesReturned, 0);
    typedef struct
    {
        ULONG ReparseTag;
        USHORT ReparseDataLength;
        USHORT Reserved;
        union
        {
            struct
            {
                USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
                USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
                USHORT PrintNameOffset;
                USHORT PrintNameLength;
                ULONG Flags;
                WCHAR PathBuffer[1];
            } SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer;
            struct
            {
                USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
                USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
                USHORT PrintNameOffset;
                USHORT PrintNameLength;
                WCHAR PathBuffer[1];
            } MountPointReparseBuffer;
            struct
            {
                UCHAR  DataBuffer[1];
            } GenericReparseBuffer;
        };
    } REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;
    REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER* pRDB = reinterpret_cast<REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*>(buffer);
    if (pRDB->ReparseTag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK)
    {
        int nameLength = pRDB->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength / sizeof(wchar_t);
        wchar_t* pName = (wchar_t*)((char*)pRDB->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer + pRDB->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset);
        int bytesWritten = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pName, nameLength, link, linksize, NULL, NULL);
        return bytesWritten;
    }
    CloseHandle(h);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).